# Proving that $h(x,t) = tx_0 + (1-t)x$ is continuous for $x \in \Bbb R ^n$ and $t \in \Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I'm trying to show that $h(x,t) = tx_0 + (1-t)x$ is continuous for $x \in \Bbb R ^n$ and $t \in \Bbb R$.

I can prove that if $f,g: X \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ for a metric space $X$ are continuous then $f + g$ is continuous, but I'm having a hard time showing:

**If $f : X \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ and $g : Y \rightarrow \Bbb R$ are continuous, then $g*f$ is continuous.**

I see that the continuity of $h$ follows from the two facts above but I'm having trouble making any progress.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The proof is essentially the same as in Euclidean space. We want to show that $f\cdot g$ is continuous in the point $(x_1,y_1)\in X\times Y$. Now pick $(x_2,y_2)\in X \times Y$, then we compute
$$ \vert f(x_1)g(y_1) - f(x_2)g(y_2) \vert = \vert f(x_1)(g(y_1)-g(y_2)) + (f(x_1)-f(x_2))g(y_2) \vert
\leq \vert f(x_1) \vert \cdot \vert g(y_1) - g(y_2) \vert + \vert f(x_1) - f(x_2) \vert \cdot \vert g(y_2) \vert
\leq \vert f(x_1) \vert \cdot \vert g(y_1) - g(y_2) \vert + \vert f(x_1) - f(x_2) \vert \cdot \vert g(y_2) - g(y_1) \vert +  \vert f(x_1) - f(x_2) \vert \cdot \vert g(y_1) \vert.$$
Now use the continuity of $f$ and $g$. Can you finish from here?

**Added:** Let $\varepsilon >0$, by the continuity of $f,g$ there exists $\delta_f, \delta_g>0$ such that $d_X(x_1, x_2)<\delta_f$ and $d_Y(y_1,y_2)< \delta_g$ implies $\vert f(x_1) -f(x_2) \vert < \min\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+ \vert f(x_1)\vert + \vert g(y_1) \vert)}, 1\}$ and $\vert g(y_1) - g(y_2) \vert < \min\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+ \vert f(x_1)\vert + \vert g(y_1) \vert)}, 1\}$. Using the inequality above, we get
$$ \vert f(x_1)g(y_1) - f(x_2)g(y_2) \vert 
\leq \vert f(x_1) \vert \cdot \vert g(y_1) - g(y_2) \vert + \vert f(x_1) - f(x_2) \vert \cdot \vert g(y_2) - g(y_1) \vert +  \vert f(x_1) - f(x_2) \vert \cdot \vert g(y_1) \vert
\leq (\vert f(x_1) \vert + \vert g(y_1) \vert) \min\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+ \vert f(x_1)\vert + \vert g(y_1) \vert)}, 1\} + \left(\min\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{2(1+ \vert f(x_1)\vert + \vert g(y_1) \vert)}, 1\}\right)^2
< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$
Hence, we for $d_{X\times Y}((x_1,y_1);(x_2,y_2)) < \min\{ \delta_f, \delta_g\}$ we have (as $d_{X\times Y}((x_1,y_1);(x_2,y_2))= d_X(x_1,x_2) + d_Y(y_1,y_2)$) that
$$ \vert f(x_1)g(y_1) - f(x_2)g(y_2) \vert < \varepsilon.$$
Thus, the function
$$ f\cdot g : (X\times Y, d_{X\times Y}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \vert \cdot
 \vert), \ (x,y) \mapsto f(x) \cdot g(y) $$
is continuous at the point $(x_1,y_1)$. However, this point was arbitrary, hence, $f\cdot g$ is continuous.

Comment: That's precisely where I get stuck when I try to prove it that way.  I can see some $|f(x)| \epsilon_f + |g| \epsilon_g$, but I'm having trouble finding a way forward.

Comment: What are you stuck on? Then I can elaborate on that point.

Comment: I think that $|f(x_1)| \epsilon_g + |g(y_2)| \epsilon_f$ for $\epsilon$'s defined by the continuity of $f$ and $g$ should be the next step, but I don't see how to lead it back to the proof.

Comment: Is it now easier? Note that $\vert f(x_1)\vert$ and $\vert g(x_1)\vert$ are just constants. Can you finish from here?

Comment: I think I'm now misunderstanding something, what are $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$?  Or, what definition of continuous are you using?

Comment: You want to show the continuity of $f\cdot g$ in the point $(x_1,y_1)\in X\times Y$. Now we need to pick $(x_2,y_2)\in X \times Y$ sufficiently close to $(x_1,y_1)$  and use the continuity of $f$ and $g$ to show that $\vert f(x_1)\cdot g(y_1) - f(x_2)\cdot g(y_2) \vert < \varepsilon$. I use the usual definition of continuity in metric spaces via epsilons and deltas.

Comment: What $\delta$ definition are you using?  I don't think I've come across showing continuity of products of metric spaces before.  Is it just $(d_X(x_2,x_1), d_Y(y_2, y_1)) \lt (\delta_X, \delta_Y)$?

Comment: The metric on the product is $d_{X\times Y}((x_1,y_1);(x_2, y_2)) :=d_X(x_1,x_2)+ d_Y(y_1,y_2)$ (there are alternative equivalent definitions, but this is the easiest).

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \lt \epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)|)$ and since $g$ is continuous $|g(y_1) - g(y_2)| \lt \epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)|)$.  Then $$|g(y_1)f(x_1) - g(y_2)f(x_2)| \le |g(y_1) - g(y_2)| |f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)||f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \lt$$


$$|f(x_1)|\epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)|) + |g(y_1)|\epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)|) = \epsilon$$.

Comment: That is almost true, you need some additional of $1/3$. Also, you will have to deal with the cross term (see my answer above, there are three terms).

Comment: Ah, I forgot the $0$'s.  If $\epsilon_f = \epsilon_g = \epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)| + 1)$, then $$|g(y_1)f(x_1) - g(y_2)f(x_2)| \le |g(y_1) - g(y_2)| |f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)||f(x_1) - f(x_2)| + |f(x_1) - f(x_2)|$$

$$\lt |f(x_1)|\epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)| + 1) + |g(y_1)|\epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)| + 1)  + \epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)| + 1)= \epsilon.$$  This seems like it works but I only used $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)|$ from the cross term.  Is this still incorrect?

Comment: You can without loss of generality assume that $0<\varepsilon \leq 1$. If you put an additional $1/3$ in your definition, then you get the desired result.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?  I'm not seeing where $1/3$ would fit into this.  And I may have overlooked something, but in my definition where am I assuming that $\epsilon$ is within $(0,1]$?

Comment: You have three terms. By your choice all of them are less or equal than $\varepsilon$, hence, if you add them up you get $3\varepsilon$, not $\varepsilon$. If $\varepsilon$ is not in $(0;1]$, how do you estimate $\varepsilon^2$ which you get from the cross term?

Comment: I'm confused, what three terms did I define that added together equal $3 \epsilon?$  Four posts back, on the bottom-most inequality I showed that the sum of $|f(x_1)| \epsilon_f + |g(y_1)| \epsilon_g + \epsilon_f = \epsilon$ for $\epsilon_f = \epsilon_g = \epsilon / (|f(x_1)| + |g(y_1)| + 1)$ is equal to $\epsilon.$  I'm still unsure of why the cross term is necessary.  Don't I just have to show that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ that $|f(x_1)g(y_1) - f(x_2)g(x_2)| \lt \epsilon$ with the appropriate conditions for $\delta$?

Comment: Either you get three terms or you have a factor $\vert g(y_2)\vert$ which you need to control. Your computation some comments ago had that typo.

Comment: Ah, I see what mistake I made - I confused myself with the subscripts.  Then let $a = f(x_1)$ and $b = g(y_1)$, then I need to find an $\epsilon_f$ and $\epsilon_g$ such that $a \epsilon_f + b \epsilon_g + \epsilon_f \epsilon_g = \epsilon$.  I see now where the cross term comes into play but I'm still not seeing where the $1/3$ has to be or what either $\epsilon_{f/g}$ must equal to have this equality.

Comment: I added the details.